# How do the values in ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs work

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm trying to understand gestures, but I'm having a hard time understanding how the they actually work.

I've put the following code in, but it's not returning what I would expect.

```
public void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("last positionX was {0}. Current positionX is {1}.  Difference between the 2: {2}", _previousPositionX, e.Position.X, e.Position.X - _previousPositionX);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("delta x: {0}", e.Delta.Translation.X);
        _previousPositionX = e.Position.X;
}
```

I would expect this code to print out something like

---

last positionX was 0. Current positionX is 23.

Difference between the 2: 23

delta x: 23

---

last positionX was 23. Current positionX is 33.

Difference between the 2: 10

delta x: 10

---

last positionX was 33. Current positionX is 53.

Difference between the 2: 20

delta x: 20

---

However what I'm getting is

---

last positionX was 298.787872314453. Current positionX is 314.760620117188.

Difference between the 2: 15.9727478027344

cumulative x: -181.818176269531

delta x: -44.5818138122559

---

last positionX was 314.760620117188. Current positionX is 326.009094238281.

Difference between the 2: 11.2484741210938

cumulative x: -210.036361694336

delta x: -28.2181797027588

---

last positionX was 326.009094238281. Current positionX is 350.893920898438.

Difference between the 2: 24.8848266601563

cumulative x: -212.509078979492

delta x: -2.47272729873657

---

Neither e.Delta.Translation.X or e.Cumulative.Translation.X seem to match the difference between what the e.Position.X was last time the eventhandler was called and the current time.  This is all in one swipe gesture.   How do I find out where the rectangle is at the start/end of the the ManipulationDelta and how far it has moved since the last one?  I want to know where the current position of the rectangle is, because I don't want the user to be able to move it offscreen.

Thanks

Comment: There always seems to be a delay as well when moving an object using e.Delta.Translation. Ie using private TranslateTransform _dragTranslation; 

    `public void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        _dragTranslation.X = e.Delta.Translation.X;  
    }`  
works in that it moves the retangle around, but the movement is very delayed and moves a fraction of a second after my finger. Is this really the right way to do it?